# Meaning of "You are on a 1 day streak"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I've got this sentence in an email from an internet site where I learn foreign languages. What does it mean?

> Way to go! You are on a 1 day streak!

Answer (score 4):

A [streak](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/streak) is

> a period of repeated success or failure

In this case, it's a task you have fulfilled a *consecutive* number of days. A 1 day streak isn't really a streak, because there is no 'repeat'. If you fulfil the task tomorrow again, you will be on a 2 day streak. Next day, you could be on a 3 day streak. If at any day in the future you don't fulfil the task, you will be counting from 1 again.

Comment: So, "you're on a one-day streak" is a sarcastic remark.

Comment: In other words, those who programmed that site either did it on purpose (knowing that 1-day streak is not a streak) or didn't realize it might sound sarcastic.  Like those who create the UI "there are 1 items in your cart"...

Comment: I think, Glorfindel is right. Definitely, it was an automatically generated email. Thank you all for your help.